# Using prototype to mimic html form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prototypejs

I have an html form generated by rails, so that when it's submitted, the rails controller can gather all the params for the rails object in one swoop with:

```
@car_object = Car.new(params[:car])
```

which results in something like:

```
@car_object.color = "red";
@car_object.make = "Honda"
```

etc...

But I also need to have the controller be able to extract the same params when submitted via prototype. I'm currently doing it like:

```
req = new Ajax.Request('/car', {
    method: 'post',
    parameters: {   authenticity_token: getAuthKey(),
                    color: color,
                    make: make
                     },
```

In which case the controller has to manually create the car object by getting the individual parameters and assigning them to the new Car object.

How would I create this Ajax request so that when the Rails controller gets it, params[:car] can extract the parameters and assign them to the new Car object on it's pwn?

Comment: if this is inline javascript or contained in an rjs file you might want to change the url from a magic string to something like     <%= url_for(:action => 'create') %>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I wasn't that far off, but in my case I needed to include the keeper_id in the following format:

```
    parameters: {   authenticity_token: getAuthKey(),
                    color: color,
                    make: make,
                    'dealership[keeper_id]': dealership_id
                },
```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Prototype in a while, so forgive the quick guess, but have you tried submitting this way instead?

```
req = new Ajax.Request('/car', {
    method: 'post',
    parameters: {
        authenticity_token: getAuthKey(),
        car: { 
            color: color,
            make: make
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure on the exact specifics of your requirements as i'm not familiar with Rails. According to [the docs](http://api.prototypejs.org/ajax/) Its possible with Prototype though to pass an object or a hash as your parameters in Ajax.Request